# Setting up a hyperlink on a field on a table

Tags: php, mysql

PRetty new to MySQL and PHP, I need to link the reference field on the second line, similar to the first line which I have used in another page.

this is looks pretty simple but I just cant get it to work, its the second line I need to get working as a hyperlink.

Thanks

```
<td><a href="update.php?Reference=<? echo $rows['Reference']; ?>">update</a></td>


 echo "<td>".$search_rs['Reference'] . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i got your question but maybe this is the answer.

```
<td>
  <a href="update.php?Reference=<? echo $rows['Reference']; ?>">update</a>
</td>
 echo "<td><a href=\"update.php?Reference={$search_rs['Reference']}\">text goes here</a></td>";
```

Note: avoid `<? ?>`, not set as default in some PHP versions.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
echo '<td><a href="update.php?Reference='.$rows['Reference'].'">'.$search_rs['Reference'].'</a></td>';
```